# Php session is not starting

Tags: php, html, session

I am working on localhost and trying to create a login system but my session is not starting, here is my php code

```
if(isset($_POST['_submit'])){
            session_start();
            if(empty($_POST['_email']) || empty($_POST['_password'])){
                echo "<script>window.alert('Invalid User EMAIL or PASSWORD!')</script>";
            }
            else{

                $email = $_POST['_email'];
                $password = $_POST['_password'];

                $select_user = "SELECT email,password FROM signup WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
                $query = mysqli_query($conn,$select_user);
                $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

                if($rows>0){
                    $_SESSION['user_email'] = $email;
                    header('Location: ../index.php');
                }
                else{
                    echo "<script>window.alert('Invalid User EMAIL or PASSWORD!')</script>";
                }

            }
        }
```

and after session start i want to change in html code, here is my code

```
<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['user_email'])){ ?>
<li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
<?php } else { ?>
<li><a href="login/index.php">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="signUp/index.php">Sign Up</a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

here is my html code of login system

```
<div class="outside">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3 glyphicon glyphicon-user" for="email"></label>
                    <div class="control-label col-sm-8">
                        <input type="_email" name="_email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3 glyphicon glyphicon-lock" for="password"></label>
                    <div class="control-label col-sm-8">
                        <input type="password" name="_password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group"> 
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-3">
                        <button name="_submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >Login</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <p>Not a User? <a href="../signUp/index.php">Sign Up</a></p>
        </div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please post your html code as well...done

Comment: html code of login system?

Comment: do you have session_start() being called in your root level index.php?  the one that you redirect to?

Comment: Okay...On all the pages that you are using or checking if any session is set, at the top of every page, include session_start(); right after your <?php tags...done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to start the session where you need to work with session

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['somekey']))
{
      //code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

declare session_start() before the `<html>` tag. see if it works.

Answer (score -1):

session_start() needs to be outside of your if-statement and is usually always run before any of your PHP code will execute.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['_submit'])){
```

Put session_start() at the top of all your PHP files where you want to check any session data.  If you have a centralized config file just put it in there.

Comment: I also start a session outside if statement but nothing happens

Comment: You have session_start at the top of your root level index.php file too?  You must put it in your index.php file if it is not there.